# Is there any way to apply customized Css to different controls in PowerBI

Tags: html, css, angular, powerbi-embedded

1. I have created a PowerBI report.
2. I saved that into PowerBI server so that i can access that URL into my Web Application with the help of iframe.
3. I am using that into the iframe in my web App(Angular5) so that i can view that in browser.
4. Everything till now is working fine.
5. But I want to change CSS of that whole content from PowerBI.

   Example:

   a) I want border-radius for dropdown.

   b) I want buttons to be of smaller size than they are.

   c) I want to apply border-radius to the dropdown Popup

   d) I wan to make all textboxes to have round corners.

I want all these changes to be made in that powerBI report. So could you please tell me the way to go ahead with these type of CSS customization for PowerBI report.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I have created PowerBI report in PowerBI desktop application and embedded that into Web app by using simple iframe.
As like:<iframe id="reportIframe" width="1200" height="600" src="PowerBIreportServerUrl?rs:Embed=true" frameborder="0px"></iframe>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I had discussion few experts from my organization as well as from MS.
The conclusion is to have **custom visuals** and go ahead with design.
Directly there is no way to apply custom CSS to PowerBI report.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot change the embedded report CSS.
All layout changes to the report should be done on Power BI Desktop or in powerbi.com